# Android | Can't build multi flavorDimension

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-flavors, android-flavordimension

I have multi dimensionFlavor as:

```
flavorDimensions "app", "endpoint"
productFlavors {
    ph {
        applicationIdSuffix ".app1"
        dimension "app"
    }
    pac {
        applicationIdSuffix ".app2"
        dimension "app"
    }
    production {
        dimension "endpoint"
        // applicationIdSuffix ".production"
    }
    staging {
        dimension "endpoint"
        // applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
    }
}
```

But I want the application id to have both the app and env name. like: `com.company.application.app1.staging`

And then comes the confusion in the directory structure to put the `google-services.json` separately for each package name.

I've tried like `app/src/app1Staging/google-services.json`

But it fails in the build.

Comment: what is your failure logs?

Answer (score 0):

`google-services.json` should be put under **assets** directory and accessed via `AssetManager`, something like `AssetManager assetMgr = activity.getAssets();`

And the paths should be organised according to your build flavors, e.g.

```
app/src/staging/assets/google-services.json
```